# Compare 2 columns in different pandas datasets and replace value if value exists in second dataset

Tags: python, pandas

I need to get a small pandas dataset of values and run through another dataset to see if they match.  If they do match, I need to replace the value.

Small pandas dataset called unacceptable_indexes:

```
    Value   Make
0   1   Honda
1   2   Mazda
2   4   Holden
3   7   Toyota
4   9   Nissan
5   10  Ford
```

Check if any of the above makes exist in this dataset called df:

```
        Tried   Tested  Free    Cost    VehicleMake
0       False   False   False   40000.0 Kia
1       False   False   False   40000.0 Holden
2       False   False   False   40000.0 Kia
3       False   False   True    40000.0 Toyota
4       False   False   False   40000.0 Toyota
5       False   False   False   40000.0 VW
```

If exists then I need to change VehicleMake to 'CombinedMakes'

So in the second dataframe, indexes 1 (Holden), 3 (Toyota), 4 (Toyota) would be changed to VehicleMake = 'CombinedMakes'

```
        Tried   Tested  Free    Cost    VehicleMake
0       False   False   False   40000.0 Kia
1       False   False   False   40000.0 CombinedMakes
2       False   False   False   40000.0 Kia
3       False   False   True    40000.0 CombinedMakes
4       False   False   False   40000.0 CombinedMakes
5       False   False   False   40000.0 VW
```

I tried this but it is not working and it is also extremely slow:

```py
df['VehicleMake'] = df['VehicleMake'].replace(df.VehicleMake.isin(unacceptable_indexes.Make), "CombinedMakes")
```

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated!  Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
df.loc[df['VehicleMake'].isin(unacceptable_indexes['Make']), 'VehicleMake'] = "CombinedMakes"
```

This should work. You search for what you want on the left, then assign it to the right side of the equation.

Comment: Thanks Ben and thanks for the explanation, makes perfect sense, except now I am getting an error: KeyError: "['CombinedMakes' 'CombinedMakes' 'CombinedMakes' ... 'CombinedMakes'\n 'CombinedMakes' 'CombinedMakes'] not in index"

Comment: I made a slight mistake with the second part of the loc as dTanMan stated, I fixed it with my code.

Answer (score 1):

[Ben Pap's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55682481/4810567) is almost correct. It should be

```
df.loc[df['VehicleMake'].isin(unacceptable_indexes['Make']), 'VehicleMake'] = "CombinedMakes"
```

I'll break it down:

1) `unacceptable_indexes['Make']` gets the Make column as a pandas `Series`.

2) The `isin` function returns a boolean `Series` of relevant rows.

This allow us to select the rows where the `VehicleMake` is unacceptable. (You can try running just `df['VehicleMake'].isin(unacceptable_indexes['Make'])` to see the result)

3) The `loc` function works as `df.loc[row/s, column/s]`. So we just need to indicate we're accessing the `Make` column via a `'Make'` string, and not the whole column.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation.  Really appreciated!